# How to get result group by in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How to `get_models_by_brand` (grouped by `body_type`)?
I have those tables---->  `1.models` , `2.brands` , `3.body_type`
I want to make query that get models by brand to be group by `body_type` like below

```
{
  {
  "sedan" : ["316","318"]
  },

  {
    "coupe" : ["z3","z4"]  
  },

}
```

This is how I get the brands ---- control file

```
public function getBrands()
{
    $brands = DB::table('brands')
              ->join('countries', 'brands.country_id', 'countries.country_id')
              ->where('brands_status', 1)
              ->select('brands.brands_id','brands.brands_name','brands.brands_name_ar',
              'brands.brands_logo_url','countries.country_name','countries.country_name_ar')
              ->get()->toArray();
    return response()->json(new Response(true, $brands));
}
```

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the MySQL.

Comment: ->groupBy('body_type')->get()

Answer (score 0):

its very simple you can use **->groupBy()** in your query